# "mysql_real_escape_string" error DESPITE connecting to database..what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, prepared-statement, mysql-real-escape-string

Ok, this is driving me crazy.
My PHP version is 5.2.17, MySQL version is 5.1.59

My javascript(jquery)is :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$.post("file.php",{"dropTable":tableName}, function(data){});});
```

which is an ajax call on page load

My "file.php" contains the following code :

```
    <?php

        require_once"getDBParameters.php";

        $dbParameters = getDBParameters();
        if($dbc = mysqli_connect($dbParameters['db_host'], $dbParameters['db_username'], $dbParameters['db_pass'], $dbParameters['db_name'])){

            if(isset($_POST['dropTable'])){
                $dropTable= $_POST['dropTable'] ;               
                $escapedRealString = mysql_real_escape_string($dropTable, $dbc );

                echo ($escapedRealString );
                exit();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I get a PHP error saying :

```
    mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in file.php on line 9
```

The same connection works perfectly if I use prepared statements, however, I cannot use a prepared statement in this case since I'm dropping a MYSQL table based on user input :

```
    DROP TABLE $dropTable
```

The PHP manual says I cannot use prepared statements like :

```
    prepare("DROP TABLE ?")
```

I can assure you that the function "getDBParameters" is working fine.
Whats the problem ? Any other solution ?

Comment: `I cannot use a prepared statement in this case since I'm dropping a MYSQL table based on user input`   wow...easy game is easy.

Comment: @Damien Hey, he's at least offering a clean interface. No Bobby Tables necessary. ;o)

Comment: @DamienPirsy , yeah...what I'm developing is a backend for a private site... its gonna have ONLY ONE user logging in... still, gotta take precautions...thanks for your very very very valuable comment tho

Comment: @dinchakpianist Sure. Imho you should also at least provide some confirmation before doing such a destructive action; and why dropping a whole table, and not just emptying it? Are those temp tables? If the database user has create/drop table privileges is still risky. And everything should be behind a damn good auth system

Comment: If I may throw in may two cent: dropping tables should never ever be something the user needs to do, **unless you're writing a database administration system** like phpMyAdmin. Otherwise *"the database"* is an implementation detail that the end user needs to know nothing about.

Comment: @deceze My user does not know I'm dropping tables...he knows nothing about the php-sql "structure" being used, neither does he know those languages .. thanks for the responses and comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysqli_connect
     ^
mysql_real_escape_string
     ^
```

You're mixing MySQL***i*** and MySQL functions. They're entirely different, incompatible extensions. Use [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), you can't use the mysql escaping function.

You can also use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).

Note that because the PHP mysql and mysqli libraries are distinct, the parameter types are too.  mysql uses a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), while mysqli is an [object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

EDIT: As noted, dropping tables based on user input is dangerous.